# Not getting the available room between two dates when there are multiple category in one booking

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

**Fiddle**

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84cd10f595c0219e0a414d5b039613bf

My problem is the query that is suppose to get the available room based on checkin and checkout(rooms not booked) is not working when I use it in laravel, but is working when I test in MySQL.Even if I book all the rooms it still shows that all the rooms is available(see fiddle).

**Expected output**

```
category    count
standard    0
quad        0
family      0
barkada     0
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I'm using MySQL

Comment: So the problem is with laravel. Everything you've posted is fine.

Comment: Incidentally, can users book rooms by the second? If not, why are you storing seconds !?!

Comment: @Rei . . . You really need to do a better job of explaining your problem and your data.  You can start with "I have X tables.  These are . . . ".  Then, "I want to get . . . ".  Or something similar.

Comment: Good that you use DbFiddle!

Comment: I figured it out, the problem is in laravel, it requires the date to have a single quote. I will do a better job at asking questions in the future. Thank you